# Use of metochos versus koinonos in the Book of Hebrews

Tags: hermeneutical-approaches, hebrews, historical-interpretation

Can one draw any inference regarding whether the author regards the individuals addressed in Hebrews 6:4-6 as possessors or professors when he uses μετόχους  rather than κεκοινώνηκεν (2:14) to describe partakers of the Holy Spirit? What inference can be drawn from the use of inclusive pronouns in verses 5:11-6:3 and 6:9-12 compared to the use of exclusive pronouns in 6:4-6? Can a inference be drawn for the use of παραπεσόντας in 6:6 rather than ἀποστῆναι (3:12) to suggest this passage is dealing with loss of rewards rather than apostasy?

Comment: I'm having trouble wrapping my head around your question.  You are asking three different questions, but it seems you view them as related in the context of "loss of rewards" vs. "apostasy".  Could you rephrase a little to make your question clearer?  Your question(s) seem(s) to be deeper than what the title of your post indicates.  Thanks.

Comment: This should be split into multiple questions.